# Building an AIR application with ANT

Tags: file, ant, build, air

I keep getting "Java Heap Space" error. What is the JVM Memory requirements to build AIR apps with ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. In the mxmlc task (or any others), make sure to set fork to true and maxmemory to at least 512m, such as:

The fork starts a new thread so the memory isn't shared. And the maxmemory let's the JVM know how much memory it can use.